# I want to eliminate one 4x4 wood column in a line

Tags: beam, column

I am planning to finish an attic space. I want to eliminate one 4x4 wood column in a line. The column is 8 ft from a load bearing wall and 12 ft from another column (which will remain). The column supports twin 2x10s with a 2x6 joists and 2x6 rafters in a simple﻿﻿ low pitch roof above. I can get at the twin 2x10s so I could bolt a microlam or even steel to reinforce this.  How can I find out what must be added to eliminate the column? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: **Pictures and/or diagram would help.** Potential snow load and/or hurricane and/or earthquake issues could be involved as those can all affect code in different areas. Though in the end I suspect the answer will be "consult a structural engineer."

Comment: What is the span of the 2x6 joist and what spacing?

Comment: Is there a joint (splice) in the 2-2x10’s at the point where the 4x4 is to be removed?